# Java applet deadlock on Chrome on Win 7 64 with either JRE 1.6.0.29 or 1.7.0.1

Tags: java, applet

I'm writing an an applet and it sometimes hangs before it even enters init() when running under Chrome (14.0.835.202 m) on Windows 7 64.

I'm using the following bit of code to create the applet (created within the <body> element), and under FF (and even Chrome when running on XP 32-bit) it runs fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var attributes = {
    id: 'JavaUploader',
    code: 'com.foo.Uploader.class',
    archive: '/java/uploader_0.0.4.jar',
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
};
var parameters = {};
var version = '1.6';
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

When it hangs it seems to deadlock when trying to get the cookie before fetching the JAR file. Here's the log (including stack dump):

```
Java Plug-in 10.1.0.8
Using JRE version 1.7.0_01-b08 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

<snip>

security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
preloader: Construct preloader delegate
preloader: Setting default preloader and progress monitor for non JNLP applets
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@942eb
preloader: Installing progress monitor true
preloader: Using preloader class: null com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter@1283826
preloader: Using default preloader
preloader: Requested to use preloader class: null
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://foo.com/java/uploader_0.0.4.jar
preloader: GrayBox: parent = sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame0,0,0,1x1,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
preloader: Added pending event 1: AppletInitEvent[type=CallConstructor]
preloader: Delivering: AppletInitEvent[type=CallConstructor]
preloader: Skipped all (0) download events prior to null
preloader: Start progressCheck thread
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
network: Cache entry found [url: http://foo.com/java/uploader_0.0.4.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
preloader: Stop progressCheck thread

<it stops here>

Dump thread stack ...
----------------------------------------------------
2011-10-25 16:50:26
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing):

"Thread-12" daemon prio=4 tid=0x05478400 nid=0x1b58 waiting on condition [0x095ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAnimationPanel2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"D3D Screen Updater" daemon prio=8 tid=0x05477c00 nid=0x1554 in Object.wait() [0x08a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x2982e5e8> (a java.lang.Object)
   at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DScreenUpdateManager.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x2982e5e8> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05477800 nid=0x1174 waiting on condition [0x08b6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   - parking to wait for  <0x24700468> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"ConsoleTraceListener" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05476000 nid=0x1208 in Object.wait() [0x0896f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x29825358> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)
   at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$ConsoleWriterThread.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x29825358> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)

"thread applet-com.foo.Uploader.class-1" prio=4 tid=0x05476400 nid=0x1958 in Object.wait() [0x0844d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x247005f8> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
   at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x247005f8> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
   at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingExecutionContext.getProxyList(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginProxySelector.select(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6bd0> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginProxySelector)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x247006f0> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
   at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x24700968> (a java.lang.Object)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x247009c0> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x24702b38> (a sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection)
   at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x24702b38> (a sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x29825d50> (a com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath)
   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6be8> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6c88> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6c88> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x05474c00 nid=0x181c waiting on condition [0x082ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacksImpl(Native Method)
   at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacks(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui.SwingConsoleWindow$2.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent$ActionStandin.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05475800 nid=0x1834 in Object.wait() [0x0851f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c6f68> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)
   at sun.plugin2.main.server.HeartbeatThread.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6f68> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)

"AWT-EventQueue-2" prio=4 tid=0x05475000 nid=0x19b4 waiting on condition [0x083af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   - parking to wait for  <0x298c7058> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Applet 1 LiveConnect Worker Thread" prio=4 tid=0x05474400 nid=0x1adc in Object.wait() [0x0833f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7138> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c7138> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread" prio=6 tid=0x05474000 nid=0x17a8 in Object.wait() [0x0826f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c71c0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c71c0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$BrowserSideObjectCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"CacheCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05473800 nid=0x1a2c in Object.wait() [0x07f7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c71e0> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c71e0> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)

"CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05459c00 nid=0x156c in Object.wait() [0x0812f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c72d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c72d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$LoadedResourceCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"SysExecutionTheadCreator" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05431000 nid=0xc8c in Object.wait() [0x080cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c72f0> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c72f0> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x05429000 nid=0x19f0 waiting on condition [0x07eaf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   - parking to wait for  <0x298c73d0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05424c00 nid=0xb00 runnable [0x0110f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
   at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x05424400 nid=0x1ac0 in Object.wait() [0x07c6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7538> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c7538> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x05423c00 nid=0x1c4 in Object.wait() [0x07cdf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c75c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c75c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java Plug-In Pipe Worker Thread (Client-Side)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x05421c00 nid=0x17a0 runnable [0x07bff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile0(Native Method)
   at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.ipc.windows.WindowsNamedPipe.read(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.read(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.readByte(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.message.AbstractSerializer.readInt(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.message.transport.SerializingTransport.read(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Timer-0" prio=6 tid=0x05401800 nid=0xb88 in Object.wait() [0x078af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7900> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c7900> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"traceMsgQueueThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x053af000 nid=0xd24 in Object.wait() [0x04d9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x2980afd8> (a java.util.ArrayList)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x2980afd8> (a java.util.ArrayList)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00989c00 nid=0x11cc runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00988c00 nid=0xd14 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00987000 nid=0x1214 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00983c00 nid=0x1764 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x00963800 nid=0x15f0 in Object.wait() [0x04e3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7b88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c7b88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00962000 nid=0x600 in Object.wait() [0x04a0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c6ba0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
   at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c6ba0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x0024dc00 nid=0x530 in Object.wait() [0x0039f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7c10> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
   at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x298c7c10> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
   at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00960c00 nid=0xe34 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0098d000 nid=0x17ec waiting on condition 

plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00960c00 nid=0xe34 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0098d000 nid=0x17ec waiting on condition 


----------------------------------------------------
Done.
```

Looking at the stack dump, my guess is that it's trying to get the cookie before fetching the applet jar (to send with the HTTP request) but the getCookie() call hangs.

I've searched online for anyone else who might have come across this problem, but haven't been able to find anything.

Has anyone else seen this? If so - is there a workaround?

**NOTE:** When this happens the Chrome page becomes totally unresponsive and I get a "Kill Page" prompt.

This happens with either JRE 1.6.0.29 or 1.7.0.1

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that if I test this on a local server (Apache running on Linux in VirtualBox on my development machine) I don't get any problems.

Comment: We've seen similar behaviour in Safari on OS X, very intermittently.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your dump I don't think you ran into a deadlock (at least not on thread level), your main thread seems to wait for a message endlessly:

```
"main" prio=6 tid=0x0024dc00 nid=0x530 in Object.wait() [0x0039f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x298c7c10> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
...
```

googling a bit for this issue I found this:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6668033

a bug concerning the use of LiveConnect (Bridge between the applet and the browser's javascript engine). I would try to turn off javascript and see if the applet still hangs (then it's something else) or if your problem is caused by this issue.

Another hint might be this link (hang specific to chrome):

https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab/issues/17

with a mentioned possible workaround.

Comment: +1 for some keen information sourcing.. *"googling a bit .. I found ..
bugs.sun.com"* I've always found it more effective to use Google rather than Sun/Oracle's own search, for trawling the bug DB. ;)

Comment: Thanks for doing the search. According to the sun.com link the bug (if it's the same one) has been fixed - but that doesn't seem the case. Also the author on github reckons the problem was trying to create the applet after the page has finished loading, but that's not true in my case. So I'm still left wondering what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your problem. Call myApplet.somefunc(); after your applet get actually started.
http://springflex.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-fix-chrome-frozon-issue-when.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it using [deploying applet example.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/runAppletFunction.html#tagAttrsParams)
Additionaly I had to modify source code of deployJava.js, because `document.write` function has refreshed page. I replaced it with `$('body').append`.
After that chrome started behave weird - it created and ran applet twice and I could communicate with the second instance because it always hangs. Using

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myApplet.someFunction();
}, 0);
```

solved this problem.
Whole my deploying script:

```
var baseurl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + Form.fields.baseUrl;
var attributes = {
    id: 'myApplet',
    code: 'main.java.myApplet.class',
    archive: baseurl + 'Applet/appletJar.jar',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
};
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, {}, '1.7');

setTimeout(function () {
    if (myApplet !== undefined && "somefunc" in myApplet) {
        myApplet.somefunc();
    }
}, 0);
```