# Applet getting hang on Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet, java-7, freeze

Apologies for the long post, but I wonder if I could get more suggestion on this before I submit a bug report to Sun.

JVM: 7u04

O/S: Windows XP SP3

Hardware: Pentium(R) Dual-Core E6700 3.20GHz, with 3.25 GB RAM.

Browse: Google Chrome version 19.0.1084.52

When the page is load Applet, it will hang until I close it. Check the window task manager,
I found if kill the Applet processor, the page won't be hang.I try to print some message on
Applet init() and start(), but these messages does not show.Only I can do is get the full 
dump by JVM as follow. Could anyone tell me why Applet hangs before it started?
Thanks for help.

```
2012-06-07 10:08:25
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode, sharing):

"thread applet-com.arcare.extend.ExtendFunc-2" prio=4 tid=0x03021400 nid=0xbe8 in Object.wait() [0x03dad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x22fa0158> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa0158> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingExecutionContext.doCookieOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingExecutionContext.getCookie(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginCookieSelector.getCookieFromBrowser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.cookie.DeployCookieSelector.getCookieInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.cookie.DeployCookieSelector.get(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2805a508> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginCookieSelector)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setCookieHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa02e8> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa0568> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa05c0> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa2738> (a sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa2738> (a sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa2850> (a com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa2910> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa29e8> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa29e8> (a sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-3" prio=4 tid=0x0301fc00 nid=0x39c waiting on condition [0x0457f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x22fa2c08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Applet 11 LiveConnect Worker Thread" prio=4 tid=0x0301e400 nid=0xcf4 in Object.wait() [0x044df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x22fa2d08> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x22fa2d08> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03eb6800 nid=0xcd0 waiting on condition [0x0357f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x2844c680> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Windows Tray Icon Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03e1d000 nid=0x92c runnable [0x043ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.sun.deploy.ui.WindowsJavaTrayIcon.mainLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.ui.WindowsJavaTrayIcon.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.ui.WindowsJavaTrayIcon$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"ConsoleTraceListener" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0315d800 nid=0xec0 in Object.wait() [0x037ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2807aaf0> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$ConsoleWriterThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2807aaf0> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=4 tid=0x03e8fc00 nid=0x980 waiting on condition [0x03d0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x28302b10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"thread applet-com.arcare.extend.ExtendFunc-1" prio=4 tid=0x031f2c00 nid=0xc08 in Object.wait() [0x03c6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2807a4b0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2807a4b0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x0314d000 nid=0xd50 waiting on condition [0x036be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacksImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleHelper.dumpAllStacks(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui.SwingConsoleWindow$2.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent$ActionStandin.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-2" prio=4 tid=0x0312b400 nid=0x270 waiting on condition [0x0375f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x2816fb78> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"JVM[id=2]-Heartbeat" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03128c00 nid=0x2f8 in Object.wait() [0x0370f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129b98> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)
    at sun.plugin2.main.server.HeartbeatThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129b98> (a sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$Heartbeat)

"Applet 10 LiveConnect Worker Thread" prio=4 tid=0x03101800 nid=0x620 in Object.wait() [0x034df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129ce8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129ce8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread" prio=6 tid=0x030f1400 nid=0x4fc in Object.wait() [0x0366f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129d70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129d70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$BrowserSideObjectCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"CacheCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x030df400 nid=0x860 in Object.wait() [0x0361f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129d90> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129d90> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)

"CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x030d9400 nid=0x568 in Object.wait() [0x035cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129e80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129e80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$LoadedResourceCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"SysExecutionTheadCreator" daemon prio=6 tid=0x030cf400 nid=0xec4 in Object.wait() [0x0339f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a000> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a000> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x030c7400 nid=0xea8 waiting on condition [0x0352f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x2812a0f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x030bf400 nid=0x4a8 runnable [0x00a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x030bdc00 nid=0xe38 in Object.wait() [0x0348f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a258> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a258> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x030bc800 nid=0xaa8 in Object.wait() [0x0343f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a2e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a2e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java Plug-In Pipe Worker Thread (Client-Side)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x030b6c00 nid=0xb60 runnable [0x033ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile0(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.ipc.windows.WindowsNamedPipe.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.AbstractSerializer.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.SerializingTransport.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Timer-0" prio=6 tid=0x03085800 nid=0x8cc in Object.wait() [0x0334f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a628> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a628> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"traceMsgQueueThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03064c00 nid=0xcc0 runnable [0x0327f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.length(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.trace.FileTraceListener.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace.firePrintlnEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02ba9800 nid=0xf24 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ba7000 nid=0xcdc waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ba2000 nid=0x4ac runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ba0800 nid=0xed8 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x02b7b800 nid=0xc10 in Object.wait() [0x02e2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a8b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a8b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02b76c00 nid=0x70 in Object.wait() [0x02ddf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28129480> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28129480> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x0087a000 nid=0xcfc in Object.wait() [0x0092f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x2812a938> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x2812a938> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02b75400 nid=0x614 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02bac000 nid=0x6c4 waiting on condition 

.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02b75400 nid=0x614 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02bac000 nid=0x6c4 waiting on condition
```

Comment: google chrome does not support <applet> tag - use <object> tag instead. If u already r, ignore this comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [applet deploy example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/runAppletFunction.html#tagAttrsParams). Script `deployJava.js` add to your page diffrent tags (applet, object or embed) according to your or your client browser.
I had big problem with unresponsive pages and I put my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885715/java-applet-deadlock-on-chrome-on-win-7-64-with-either-jre-1-6-0-29-or-1-7-0-1) - similar question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

try this site for your issue. Make sure call Applet function after applet is fully loaded
http://springflex.blogspot.com/2014/09/my-practices-to-resolve-applet-stuck.html